# Create template element/document fragment from full HTML markup

Tags: javascript, dom

It doesn’t seem possible to create a template element and parse the markup of a complete HTML document with it.

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<html></html>');
```

This snippet will yield `DocumentFragment []`. Using the full markup only yields all elements below the `head` or `body` element. In other words: The `html`, `head`, and `body` elements are stripped from the document fragment.

This is unexpected, [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template):

> Permitted content: No restrictions

The following is a workaround for this problem. `htmlElement` contains what I expected `template.content` to contain when feeding it the full markup.

```
const htmlElement = document.createElement('html');

const headElement = document.createElement('head');
headElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', headMarkup);
htmlElement.appendChild(headElement);

const bodyElement = document.createElement('body');
bodyElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', bodyMarkup);
htmlElement.appendChild(bodyElement);
```

Is there any way I can create a document fragment/element containing a full document that is not attached to the DOM?

Note: My use case is attaching a shadow DOM containing a full HTML document to a node of an existing document.

Comment: `createElement` doesn't create the element to the DOM, until it's appended/inserted to the DOM.

Comment: @Teemu `createElement` indeed doesn’t insert a document fragment in the DOM; however, that’s not the point of the question. I tried to create a document fragment with `createElement` but it didn’t work as I expected.

Comment: @kleinfreund The user Teemu is correct. Using `createElement` doesn't create the element to the DOM, until it's appended to the DOM. You should take a look at the documentation: [JavaScript/DOM/Document/createElement](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/DOM/Document/createElement#:~:text=Die%20Methode%20Document.,auch%20auf%20XML%2DDokumente%20anwenden.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) interface.

```
const htmlMarkup = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlMarkup, 'text/html');

const shadowHost = document.querySelector('.shadow-host');
const shadowRoot = shadowHost.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
shadowRoot.appendChild(doc.documentElement);
```